# How to access a video file in a directory located in my server's home directory

Tags: php

Unable to correctly use php code to load a video mp4 file stored in home directory.

Hi, I am building a WP site that sells instruction video mp4 files. To protect the files I have placed them in a directory called videos which is in the home directory (outside of the public_html directory) to protect the files from being downloaded for free. I am trying to write php code for loading the video. However, I can't access the video in /home/username/videos.

My code:

add_action('template_redirect', 'video_redirect', 5);

function video_redirect(){

```
        if (is_admin())

                    return;

        if (!is_page(videoplayerpageonmysite))

                    return;
```

$filename="/home/username/videos/videofile.mp4";

echo "  Your browser does not support the video tag.";

Each time I run the code I get a No video with supported format... error.

I'm only able to get it to load the video file when it is in the public_html folder (it works perfectly then), but not when it is located in /home/username/videos/
Please help!

Comment: ....and what is the code? Whatever you've shown there does echo that line each and every time, without checking anything

Comment: A bit of code might help. Also the web server does not have access out side the public_html. So unless you are using php to read the file and send it out. The web server cant read it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't give the browser a file path on your server's hard disk and expect it to be able to load it. It will resolve it as a relative URL, ask the HTTP server for it, and then get a 404.

You need to give the browser a URL that actually loads the file.

If you want to limit who can access it (e.g. people who have paid), then you could write a PHP program that checks to see if the request is coming from someone who has paid (i.e. Authentication + Authorization), then reads the file and outputs it in the HTTP response.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a PHP script as the source URL in the video tag and specify some identifier for which video it should load e.g. `src="loadvideo.php?id=1"` or something. (This is because the source must be a valid URL which is actually accessible on the webserver - the browser, which don't forget runs on the user's machine not the server, cannot navigate to a path on disk. If it could, then moving your files outside the public_html folder would not provide any security!)

And then when the video tag is loaded into the page, it will make a request to that URL, which causes the PHP script to run. The script must associate the provided ID with the correct file on disk, fetch the contents of that file and echo them as the response, along with appropriate headers (e.g. mime type etc). You can probably find examples of this pattern online already.

Of course the PHP script will also need to authenticate the request to make sure the requestor is a signed-in, paid user, otherwise you still aren't protecting anything. Without this last step, anyone could just visit the PHP script's URL and provide an ID until they got a result, and download the videos just as if you'd put them in the public_html folder. As long as you implement security correctly though, only users who already paid for the videos would be able to download them.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help; as you can tell I'm very new to php etc. I am using Woocommerce to sell the videos. The video product will give the user a link to a webpage after completing payment. I hope to trigger the php code when the user goes to this link (a page on my site). I was assuming that Woocommerce protects this link?

Comment: I don't know woocommerce specifically...I just know PHP as a language, so I can't comment on that. But ask yourself: why do you think that woocommerce would protect it? Have you put in place any mechanism on it to allow it to distinguish between a user who has paid, and a user who has not? I doubt it could know that automatically. Also it's not just the page where the `<video` tag lives which needs protecting, you also need to protect the script which actually provides the video - the one you must put in the "src" tag of the video. That will be a separate endpoint which also requires securing.

Comment: My code:
add_action('template_redirect', 'video_redirect', 5);
function video_redirect(){
            if (is_admin())
                       return;
            if (!is_page(videoplayerpageonmysite))
                        return;
  $filename="/home/username/videos/videofile.mp4";
echo "<video controls> <source src=\"$filename\" type=\"video/mp4\"> Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>";

Comment: Sorry not sure why you're repeating your code here in the comments?

Comment: Sorry couldn't get it to show properly above. I'm keen to understand and learn how to do this properly. Could you point me in the directory of a weblink perhaps that could get me started in the right direction?  Obviously I have lot to learn...

Comment: you've a lot less chance of it showing properly in the comments! Reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting might help you to use the tools to format it correctly in the question.